# Passing a parameter containing comma to a Batch file and replace

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I am calling my batch file as below

example.bat "abc, xyz"

Now, inside the batch file I need to replace comma `,` with `%5c%2c`

```
set var1=%1
set var1=%var1:","=%5c%2c%
```

I even tried

```
set var1=%var1:","=%%5c%%2c%
set var1=%var1:,=%5c%2c%
```

But nothing worked, it actually appends the replacement at the end instead of comma. Also, the parameter is printed with double quotes at the end.

I am expecting the result to be : `abc%5c%2c xyz`

Can some one help me out resolve this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need delayed expansion for this. Also, to get rid of the double quotes, you should use `%~1` instead of `%1`. You were right to double up on the percent signs to display literal `%`s.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var1=%~1
set var1=!var1:,=%%5c%%2c!

echo !var1!
pause
```